# MongoDB Capped Collections with Grouping

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering if there is a way to create a Mongo database collection that acts like a capped collection, but caps within groups.

For example, say I have a collection of documents that each have a username key. Is there a way to set a cap so that there can only be N number of documents for each unique username?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could add some code in your save() to delete the oldest every time you add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only supports capped collection at a collection level, You could however split your documents over multiple collections? Then create the collection with the following:

```
var numberOfDocs = 100;
db.createCollection("users", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : numberOfDocs } )
```

More reading  - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/